# Convert date into dd/MM/yyyy format in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am getting selected date as in `Thu Oct 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)` format. I want to convert this in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. What have to do in jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want more powerfull date formatting, you can use date format function written by [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com) [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var date = dateFormat(new Date("Thu Oct 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"), 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: this is good, but is there really a converter method ? because if when I am going to select date like 14 sep 2010 it is converting it as 14/9/2010 so that when I am passing this in server side at c# code by query string it is string. now it has to be convert from string to date format in .cs file ,right. but while doing this conversion it prompt me "String is not in correct format". so its need to be in correct format, what have to do then ?

Comment: ok it is working fine now , but don't know the reason. Thanks a lot.