# Get date in the 17-05-2012 format

Tags: javascript, jquery

im stuck at a problem here im getting the date in the following format

```
Wed May 16 2012 10:22:39 GMT+0500
```

i have tried

```
.toString('dd-MM-yyy');
```

but to no avail how can i parse the given format into the required one.

Comment: how do you get the first format in the first place?

Comment: @NiftyDude i'm using the telerik grid it provides the function to format the date but at the backend the `json` it maintains in that it keeps the date in the above mentioned format and i have to get the date from its hidden store

Comment: If you already have GMT difference defined you dont need to see anything in brackets

Comment: good read here: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format or seems like this question is asked earlier just a note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965365/convert-date-into-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function zeroPad(d) {
  return d < 10 ? '0' + d : d;
}

var date = new Date('Wed May 16 2012 10:22:39 GMT+0500'),
    d = zeroPad(date.getDate()),
    m = zeroPad(date.getMonth()+1);

var output = d + '-' + m + '-' + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: nb: the resulting values will not be zero padded.

Comment: @Alnitak that is not really a problem but i will be greatfull if you provide a way to do that `:)`

Comment: @john the answer has been updated to show that, albeit with a bad case of "don't repeat yourself..."

Answer (score 5):

You can use [jQuery Date Format](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat), it's a separate plugin that allows you to format dates very easily.

```
<script>
$.format.date("Wed May 16 2012 10:22:39 GMT+0500", "dd-MM-yyyy");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way in JS to do date formatting like that. You need read each item manually from the `Date` object.

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
...
```

If have a lot of work requiring date manipulation I suggest you take a look at **[Sugar JS library](http://sugarjs.com/dates)**.

Answer (score 2):

If you *happen* to already be using jQuery UI's "datepicker", there's a utility function included - `$.datepicker.formatdate()` - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate