# How to convert a DateTime value to dd/mm/yyyy in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am having a datetime object whose value is: **/Date(1475173800000)/** in jQuery. I want it to be displayed in **dd/mm/yyyy** in jQuery. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date into dd/MM/yyyy format in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965365/convert-date-into-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `new Date()` with parameter being universal time variable, `Date.prototype.toJSON()`, `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.split()` with parameter `"-"`, `Array.prototype.reverse()`, `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `"/"`

```js
var time = 1475173800000;
    
var date = new Date(time).toJSON().slice(0, 10).split("-").reverse().join("/");

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Thing is my value is like this /Date(1475173800000)/

Comment: @ShaswatSwarupSahoo Is `/Date(1475173800000)/` a string?

Comment: Needed exactly this and found it just now. Works like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) for easy and flexible date formatting. You simply use it like this:

```
var timestamp = /\/Date\((.*)\)\//;
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));
$.format.date(myDate.getTime(), "dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

Comment: After executing new Date("1475173800000"), myDate is having value as invalidDate. Checked it just now while debugging.

Comment: Added `parseInt` to convert timestamp string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest things to use for date is datejs (http://www.datejs.com/)
You can use the toString method to provide the format in which you want to get the date. There are much more useful components for date manipulation in this library. Do check it out.