# Javascript: convert datetime to DD/MM/YYYY - Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a `datetime` that looks like this:

```
2017-04-17 18:26:03
```

How can I convert this to this format using javascript or jquery:

```
17/04/2017 18:26
```

I found this question which I thought might help me but the answers are converting a timestamp but mine is not a time stamp.

[How to convert a DateTime value to dd/mm/yyyy in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813845/how-to-convert-a-datetime-value-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-jquery)

Comment: Why do you want 2 minutes to be added to it?

Comment: Your `datetime` it's just a string , right?

Comment: @trincot, LOL.. that was a typo. sorry... I dont want 2 minutes to be added to it.

Comment: @Xotic750, correct.

Comment: why you don't use momentjs?

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak, because it bloated and its an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: Momentjs is lightweight library that will take care of all the time conversion and parsing needs. Is good for the long term. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's not really overkill when what you're attempting to do is reinventing the wheel. Regex-based solutions are cumbersome and definitely not fool-proof, and it is very easy to miss edge cases when writing your own parser. [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) or even [d3's date time parser](d3 parse datetime) are good libraries to work with.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak Ha, great minds think alike :)

Comment: I'm confused. If the task is so simple, why are you asking how to do it? You're correct in that momen.js would be overkill but only if your input format never changes. If it never changes just parse out the pieces and reassemble?

Comment: @gforce301, look at the answers given bellow. specifically look at the answer given by Xotic750.. thats why i said using a bloated library is an overkill and no need for it either.

Comment: @DavidHope I think you missed the point of my comment. "If the task is so simple, why are you asking how to do it?" in reference to your comment "because it bloated and its an overkill for such a simple task.:

Comment: @gforce301, simple in terms of not needing a library to achieve it.. that's what i meant. :)... I'm not being big headed or anything.. i just said its simple because I knew it can be done in 2 or 3 lines of code and it doesn't require momentjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use simple string and array manipulation.

```js
const dateTime = '2017-04-17 18:26:03';
const parts = dateTime.split(/[- :]/);
const wanted = `${parts[2]}/${parts[1]}/${parts[0]} ${parts[3]}:${parts[4]}`;
console.log(wanted);
```

Additional: If you don't have an environment that supports [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) then you can write it like this.

```js
const dateTime = '2017-04-17 18:26:03';
const parts = dateTime.split(/[- :]/);
const wanted = parts[2] + '/' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[0] + ' ' + parts[3] + ':' + parts[4];
console.log(wanted);
```

Comment: remove the ``` from around the `${parts[2]}/${parts[1]}/${parts[0]} ${parts[3]}:${parts[4]}`. it took me hours to figure out why this code was throwing an error. other than that it works fine.

Comment: They are required with how it is currently written. It is a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) If you remove them then you must use string concatenation.

Comment: I don't know how, without them you should get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` Can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates it working without them?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a regular expression within a `replace` call:

```
input.replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)(.*):\d+$/, '$3/$2/$1$4');
```

```js
var input = '2017-04-17 18:26:03';
var result = input.replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)(.*):\d+$/, '$3/$2/$1$4');
console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation

- `^`: match start of the string.
- `(\d+)`: capture group that matches digits. A captured group can be back-referenced with `$1` for the first group, `$2` for the second ... etc. in the second argument.
- `:\d+$`: match a colon followed by digits and the end of the string (`$`): as this is not captured, this part (seconds) will be omitted in the result.

Comment: Thats a hell lot of regex. :) Could you please explain me. I am trying to understand it

Comment: Added some explanations... Tell me if something needs clarification.

Comment: I don't the `^` in your answer?

Comment: @Xotic750, Added it just now. I only had it in the snippet. Works either way, but I prefer to include it as it makes clear we want to have a match on the complete input, not just the ending part of it.

Answer (score 2):

try to create a function that format your date. here is an example that i wrote.

```js
function formate(date) {
    if (typeof date == "string")
        date = new Date(date);
    var day = (date.getDate() <= 9 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate());
    var month = (date.getMonth() + 1 <= 9 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1));
    var dateString = day + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();

    return dateString;
}
console.log(formate("2017-04-17 18:26:03"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse('2017-04-17 18:26:03'); // 1492467963000
var date = new Date(timestamp).toJSON();           // "2017-04-17T22:26:03.000Z"
var dateStr = date.slice(0, 10).split("-").reverse().join("/") // "17/04/2017"
                .concat(' ')
                .concat(date.slice(11, 16));       // "22:26"

console.log(dateStr)
"17/04/2017 22:26"
```

Comment: What's wrong? He knows how to convert timestamp to date, I showed how to convert string to timestamp... If I misunderstood the question it's not the reason to downvote. Just let me know what I did wrong in comments to my answer - it's simple.

Comment: Unfortunately there are quite a few trigger happy fingers on STO. you could be giving a correct answer and still get downvoted. same goes for the questions.. you could be asking a valid question and still get downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. You should not make reference to a 'link'. You should explain what is in the 'link'. The answer is a little confusing.