# how to retrieve messages after a given point of time using javascript and gmail API?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I have a web page that uses gmail API and javascript to deal with gmail messages. I am stuck at a point where I want to retrieve the messages after a particular timestamp.

This is part of my code that lists the mails

```
{
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'maxResults': 10

 });
```

I want to list the messages after the longdate `1531958459000`.

My attempt was as below

```
{
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'after':'1531958459000',
      'maxResults': 10

 });
```

and it doesn't seem to work. Instead getting messages after that time, I am getting 10 messages at random, like the code without the `after` part.

Any help?

Comment: try this var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'maxResults': {maxResult:'10'},

 });

Comment: @Amine Ramoul, The question is about getting messages after a particular timestamp, your suggestion does not answer it; sorry.

Comment: i know that the max Result doesn't work yet, it'll take a lot of time for recurcivity if you init it, so you are not looking at the right place look at this post : https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/469

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues with your code here.

First, you can't put the field `after` in the request body. However, you have the `q` field which can be used to input Gmail queries, just as in the Gmail app. Check the documentation for more details: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Second, it seems that the `after` query doesn't support timestamp in milliseconds, but rather in seconds.

So, your code should look like this:

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
  'userId': 'me',
  'q':'after:1531958459',
  'maxResults': 10
});
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, the additional query parameters accept `'q':` as a query and any parameters. These parameters should match the format of a regular gmail inbox search according to [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).

So I had to change the long date into `yyyy/mm/dd` format. I did it using the hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813845/how-to-convert-a-datetime-value-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-jquery).

And then amended my code like below:

```
{
var ld = new Date(lastupdatedtime).toJSON().slice(0, 10).split("-").reverse().join("/");//lastupdated time in google search query string like format
var cd = new Date(+ new Date()).toJSON().slice(0, 10).split("-").reverse().join("/");//the current time in google search query string like format
var search_query = "after:"+ld+" before:"+cd;
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',          
      'q': search_query,
      'maxResults': 10//the number of results to check through

    });
```

and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by number of days then you can use the following syntax for checking mails from last 7 days:

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
 'userId': 'me',
 'q':'after:1531958459',
 'maxResults': 10
});
```